# Problems with my google gadget

Tags: hosting, google-gadget

For my gadget the title appears blank. I cannot get it listed when I search for my gadget. Need some explanation as to what to do. Here is the xml link to my gadget:

http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/115976558690780681327/the-twitter-search.xml

PS: yes I use the google gadget editor to do the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see from the link to the xml what the problem might be. i assume you have a line like this?

```
<ModulePrefs title="WFCC" height="800" >
```

if not you need one. if you have and you still have the prolme post the whole xml here and i will look at it.